# Google gsutil auth without prompt

Tags: docker, gcloud, gsutil

I want to use gsutil inside a Docker container. I have created an O2Auth Service Account JSON file.

How can I setup gsutil auth to use the JSON config file and execute commands without prompting?

Currently I get something like this:

```
$ gsutil config -e
It looks like you are trying to run "/.../google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py config".
The "config" command is no longer needed with the Cloud SDK.
To authenticate, run: gcloud auth login
Really run this command? (y/N) y
This command will create a boto config file at /.../.boto
containing your credentials, based on your responses to the following questions. 
What is the full path to your private key file?
```

What command/parameters/setup do I have to use to circumstance prompts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved this issue by executing:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/opt/gcloud/auth.json
```

The whole example and finished container can be found here: [blacklabelops/gcloud](https://github.com/blacklabelops/gcloud)

Comment: Is there a way to auth with env vars instead of the json file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want gsutil only and bypass the prompt you can do it easily with an expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn gsutil config -e
expect "What is the full path to your private key file?" { send "/path/your.key\r" }
expect "Would you like gsutil to change the file permissions for you? (y/N)" { send "y\r" }
expect "What is your project-id?" { send "your-projet-42\r" }
interact
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-o Credentials:gs_service_key_file=<path to JSON file>` does the good work, using the boto configuration override parameters as documented at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions

```
$ gsutil -v
gsutil version: 4.57
$ gsutil -o Credentials:gs_service_key_file=key.json ls -al gs://bucket/filename
79948  2021-05-24T02:12:25Z  gs://bucket/filename#1111111145678393  metageneration=2
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions don't work for me.

What solved this problem for me is the following

1. Set the `gs_service_key_file` in the `[Credentials]` section of the boto config file (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil))
2. Activate your service account with `gcloud auth activate-service-account`
3. Set your default project in `gcloud config`

Dockerfile snipped:

```
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS /.gcp/your_service_account_key.json
ENV GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID your-project-id

RUN echo '[Credentials]\ngs_service_key_file = /.gcp/your_service_account_key.json' \
    > /etc/boto.cfg
RUN mkdir /.gcp
COPY your_service_account_key.json $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS


RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS --project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
RUN gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

using only gsutil:

first run this command to configure the authentication manually

```
gsutil config -a
```

This will create /root/.boto file with the needed credentials.
Copy that path/file into your docker image.

gsutil will now work with those credentials.